# UWP - ListView vertical scrolling view changed

Tags: c#, listview, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, scrollviewer

How can to use `ListView` inside `ScorllVeiwer` and don't break the **UI virtualization** ? I need to use `ScrollViewer ViewChanged`

I have too many Item in my `ListView` and load more by reach the end of `ListView` so if the ui virtualization break ,this cause the memory leak and low performance.

Comment: A virtualized list only virtualizes what should not be rendered. When there is no size to the outer container, it must render everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need restore virtualization by setting a width and height on the listview.